# I would like to create a basic draganddrop with using hittestobject at actionscript but I am stuck.. I think

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
stop();

btn1ileri.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, ileri1);
function ileri1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    nextFrame();
}
```

There are 3 targets `dogrucevap1`, `dogrucevap2` and `dogrucevap3`. There are also 28 puzzle pieces.

The purpose is to drag the puzzle pieces (`cvp1,cvp2,..cvp28`) to the targets.

Puzzles pieces wont be collided after sticking to the targets, there will be only 1 puzzle piece at each target. So if puzzle pieces collide with each other they will be return to their first position.

I couldn't manage to return the pieces to their original positions.

please check `returnfirstposition()`

```
var puzzle:MovieClip=new MovieClip(); 
var puzzleparcalari:String;
var ilkX:int;
var ilkY:int;
for (var i:int=1; i<=28; i++)
{
    puzzleparcalari = "cvp" + i;
    puzzle = this[puzzleparcalari];//this["cvp" + i].buttonMode = true;
    this["cvp" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,surukle);
    this["cvp" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,birak);
}


function kontrol(e:Event)   // checking recording first positions as ilkX and ilkY
{
    this["cvp" + i].addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , kontrol);
    ilkX = this["cvp" + i].x;
    ilkY = this["cvp" + i].y;//this["cvp" + i].removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , kontrol);
}




function surukle(e:MouseEvent)  // starting drag and tracing x position 
{
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
    ilkX = e.currentTarget.x;
    ilkY = e.currentTarget.y;//e.currentTarget.buttonMode = true;
    trace(e.currentTarget.x);
}


var kutucuk:MovieClip=new MovieClip();
var kutucukismi:String;//d1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,surukle);
 function returnfirstposition()  /creating return first position function
{
    this.puzzle.x = ilkX;
    this.puzzle.y = ilkY;
}
function birak(e:MouseEvent)
{
    e.currentTarget.stopDrag();

    for (var k:int=1; k<=3; k++)
    {
        kutucukismi = "dogrucevap" + k;
        kutucuk = this[kutucukismi];



        if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(this.kutucuk))
        {
            e.currentTarget.x = ilkX;
            e.currentTarget.y = ilkY;
            trace("kutucuk");


            for (var i:int=1; i<=28; i++)
            {
                puzzleparcalari = "cvp" + i;
                puzzle = this[puzzleparcalari];
                if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(this.puzzle))
                {
                    e.currentTarget.x = this.kutucuk.x;
                    e.currentTarget.y = this.kutucuk.y;
                    trace("this puzzle a değdi");
                }
                else
                {

                    returnfirstposition();


                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if "cvp" + i is a movieclip, you can just add "originalX" and "originalY" proporties to it and use them to return the movieclip:

//add this to your first loop:

```
for (var i:int=1; i<=2; i++)
{
    puzzleparcalari = "cvp" + i;
    puzzle = this[puzzleparcalari];
    this["cvp" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,surukle);
    this["cvp" + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,birak);
    this["cvp" + i].originalX=this["cvp" + i].x;
    this["cvp" + i].originalY=this["cvp" + i].y;
}

//and then in you drop function (e.currentTarget is the dropped piece):

if (e.currentTarget.hitTestObject(this.puzzle))
                {
                    e.currentTarget.x = this.kutucuk.x;
                    e.currentTarget.y = this.kutucuk.y;
                    trace("this puzzle a değdi");
                }
                else
                {

                    e.currentTarget.x =  e.currentTarget.originalX;
                     e.currentTarget.y =  e.currentTarget.originalY;

                }
```